# CSS3 Transforms rotate and alignment

Tags: css, transform

I have a regular unordered list with a few list items acting as menu navigation - pretty standard. I've rotated the list items, which rotate from the center. The menu titles in the list vary so it looks a little odd. I've used transform-origin to change the rotate to the left of the items, rather than the center, but as it rotates like an arm, the gaps between words are different. Is there any way to avoid this? So it rotates from the left but the gaps between each word is consistent?

```
<ul> 
     <li><a href="#">Culture</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Eat &amp; Drink</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Field Trips</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Happenings</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Locals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our City</a></li>
</ul>​

ul {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
ul li {
    font-size: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
}​
```

I've included two jsFiddles for you. One with the transform on the list items, and one with the transform and the transform-origin.

http://jsfiddle.net/9eNnN/

http://jsfiddle.net/aKXnz/

Thanks guys,
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for, I believe you just need to set a consistent width on the li - something like this:

```
li { width: 5%; } // you may need to play around with this value
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eNnN/3/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I overlooked this. I feel almost bad for asking now, but thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: Np. The only thing to keep in mind is that if you're using a relative measure like I've done here, it will scale relative to the container and the text could wrap if the ul gets narrow enough. It can easily be prevented by using a fixed pixel width or a min-width on the ul.

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to see a solution only using CSS !!

In the mean time, I can give you a javascript solution to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/aKXnz/1/

In the CSS, define your menu as `position:absolute`. This will put all your links on the left border (one over the other).

In the Javascript

```
var myLis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i= 0, len = myLis.length; i< len; i++)
{
    myLis[i].style.left = (30*i) + 'px';
}​
```

Simply, go through your menu and define distance from the left to be each time larger (linearly). You'll get what you want :)